# Flutter: Image only updates on the firebase database after adding breakpoints to vscode

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am facing a weird problem that I haven't faced anywhere before, I am new to flutter and I am trying to upload images. the image uploads to the firebase storage but doesn't change inside the database. UNLESS I add a breakpoint to vscode, then it works both ways.

here is my code

```
  Future<void> uploadCoverPic() async {
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? file = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    print('${file?.path}');
    String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    Reference referenceDirImages = storageRef.child('usersCoverPics');
    Reference refImagetoupload = referenceDirImages.child(uniqueFileName);

    try {
      refImagetoupload.putFile(File(file!.path));
      _x = await refImagetoupload.getDownloadURL(); // I was adding a breakpoint here to see the value of _x but it solved my problem

      UserModel user = UserModel(id: widget.user.id, coverImage: _x);
      FirebaseServices.updateCoverPic(user);
    } catch (error) {}

  }
```

```
  static void updateProfilePic(UserModel user) {
    userRef.doc(user.id).update({'profilePicture': user.profilePicture});
  }
```

what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `putFile()` function is asynchronous, so your code is not waiting for a response from it before executing the code below. The reason why putting a breakpoint fixes your problem, is that you are pausing the execution of the code.

Read more about `putFile()` on the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files#upload_from_a_file).

To fix your code, add `await`.

```
try {
      await refImagetoupload.putFile(File(file!.path));
      _x = await refImagetoupload.getDownloadURL();

      UserModel user = UserModel(id: widget.user.id, coverImage: _x);
      FirebaseServices.updateCoverPic(user);
    } catch (error) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add await when you receive the response. Like this below

```
  Future<void> uploadCoverPic() async {
ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
XFile? file = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
print('${file?.path}');
String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
Reference referenceDirImages = storageRef.child('usersCoverPics');
Reference refImagetoupload = referenceDirImages.child(uniqueFileName);

try {
  refImagetoupload.putFile(File(file!.path));
  _x = await refImagetoupload.getDownloadURL(); // I was adding a breakpoint here to see the value of _x but it solved my problem

  UserModel user = await UserModel(id: widget.user.id, coverImage: _x);
  FirebaseServices.updateCoverPic(user);
} catch (error) {}
```

}